# Copy the file in second column when the first column match

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to copy the files listed in the 2nd column of a text file to directory `dir1`, if the 1st column is "include" or "Include". my script just prints out all lines without copying the files.

**main_file**

```
lines here
another line
Include 'file1'
include 'file2'
endoffile
```

**desired output**
file1 & file2 copied in the dir1 directory

**my script**

```
awk 'tolower($1)=="include"{cp $2 dir1}' main_file
```

Comment: With `GNU` sed: `sed -n 's/$include/cp /I; tx; d; :x; s/$/ dir1/; e' main_file`

Comment: Is the name of the file being copied `'file'` or `file`? In the latter case, do we always have single quotes to delimit the file name? How is then a file name represented, which has a single quote as part of the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform an OS operation (eg, `cp`) from within `awk` you'll want to look at the `system()` function, eg:

```
awk -F"'" 'tolower($1) ~ /^include / {system("cp \"" $2 "\" dir1")}' main_file
```

---

Since the objective here is to perform an OS-level file copy it may be more straightforward to do this in `bash` ...

Adding a file with spaces in the name and creating the files/dir:

```
$ cat main_file
lines here
another line
Include 'file1'
include 'file2'
include 'file3 with spaces'
endoffile

$ touch file1 file2 'file3 with spaces'
$ mkdir dir1
```

One idea:

```
while IFS="'" read -r _ fname _
do
    cp "$fname" dir1
done < <(grep -i '^include ' main_file)
```

Before running either set of code (`awk`, `bash`):

```
$ ls -l dir1
                     # no output => nothing in directory
```

After running either set of code (`awk`, `bash`):

```
$ ls -l dir1
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 30 Jun 29 10:50  file1
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 90 Jun 29 10:50  file2
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None  0 Jun 29 10:50 'file3 with spaces'
```

**NOTE:** both solutions (`awk`, `bash`) assume the file names are always wrapped in single quotes *and* the file names do not include any single quotes

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain what your code

```
awk 'tolower($1)=="include"{cp $2 dir1}' main_file
```

is actually doing

`tolower($1)=="include"` does case-insensitive comparison, this bit more sensitive that *1st column is "include" or "Include".* (which would be expressed as `$1=="include"||$1=="Include"`) as it also holds for INCLUDE, InClUdE and so on, but if these do not appear or should be treated same way will be ok.

`{cp $2 dir1}` does string concatenation, as `cp` and `dir1` were not defined, GNU `AWK` assumes that they are empty strings. As you did not instruct GNU `AWK` what to do with effect of concatenation nothing is printed (at least in GNU Awk 5.1.0, which I used for testing).

As far as I know GNU `AWK` has not function for copying files, however you might use GNU `AWK` to prepare set of instructions for `bash` following way

```
awk 'tolower($1)=="include"{print "cp " $2 " dir1"}' main_file | bash
```

Keep in mind that such solution is prone to breakage, as it did not care about dir1 existence and might malfunction if there is `'` inside name of file, so if possible consider using language which sports features for dealing with copying files.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat main_file 
lines here
another line
Include 'file1'
include 'file2'
include 'file3 with spaces'
endoffile

$ grep -i "^include " main_file | xargs -n2 sh -c '[ -f "$1" ] && cp "$1" dir1/'

$ ls dir1
file1   file2  'file3 with spaces'
```